# Convert.FromBase64String gives different length results from same length

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have broken large files into 100,000 byte chunks. As I grab each chunk and "shrink" it, one chunk comes out with 100,002 bytes! Why?
Here is my fetch code:

```
While (numBytesToRead > 0)
    Dim nx As Integer = fsSourceSubseq.Read(FH, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead)
    If (nx = 0) Then
        Exit While
    End If
    numBytesRead = (numBytesRead + nx)
    numBytesToRead = (numBytesToRead - nx)
End While`
FileHolder = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FH)
fsSourceSubseq.Close()

bytWholeFileHolder = Convert.FromBase64String(FileHolder)
```

Then I record each chunk:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("c:\2atest\bytesFH" & Chuck & ".txt", FH, False)                         

 My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("c:\2atest\bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK" & Chuck & ".txt", bytWholeFileHolder, False)
```

For my 5 chunks, I get this:

```
bytesFH1.txt   = 133,336
bytesFH2.txt   = 133,336
bytesFH3.txt   = 133,336
bytesFH4.txt   = 133,336
bytesFH5.txt   = 133,336
bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK1.txt    = 100,000
bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK2.txt    = 100,000
bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK3.txt    = 100,000
bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK4.txt    = 100,000
bytWholeFileHolderSHRUNK5.txt    = 100,002
```

The content of each chunk is different, so I can't compare except for length.

Comment: What are the last two bytes in your chunks?

Comment: The interesting thing is using NotePad to open byteWholeFileHolderSHRUNK 1, 2, 3 it thinks they are Unicode and shows Asian characters :"㋕鸛䴨颍ᛏ䃾஑﾿ᇳꌠ㗉佦떩" Opening #4, Notepad thinks ANSI and shows: "øz%¢ç*}¥:ÞæÁp¶ð+×C©Ô»£"
The last 2 bytes are 4s

Answer (score 0):

Base64 converts every 3 bytes onto 4 bytes of output. Padding is added at the end of the Base64 result if the source data is not evenly divisible by 3 bytes.

This means that several strings of varying length can all result in the same length Base64 result. This also means that a given length Base64 result may decode to a source that can vary by up to two bytes in length.

Post your actual files for further analysis and explanation.